# I started to get ASP .NET MVC CORE localhost:18200 error suddenly

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I was working on my asp.net mvc project

But suddenly I get this error on my main page (localhost:18200) :

`.NET Core 4.6.26614.01 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.0.1-rtm-125    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362    |   Need help?`

Do you have any idea why I get this error ?

Comment: Nothing comes suddenly. check what change has happened, any installation, nuget package updagrade , e.t.c.

Comment: Do you publish to IIS,you could check IIS log file from https://codar.club/blogs/an-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application.html. Or enable [development IIS support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to  launch the site with the VS debugger attached.